# When using the Angular APP_Initializer to initialize a service, how can I use a value from another service inside the service being initialised?

Tags: angular, featuretoggle, launchdarkly

I am integrating a feature toggle service called launch darkly into my Angular application.
I followed the guidance here: https://launchdarkly.com/blog/integrating-feature-flags-in-angular-v4/

However I noticed that on occasion my application would render on screen before fetching the flags. I want the flags to always be accurate, so I used the APP_Initializer to ensure the launchdarkly.service.ts loaded the flags before loading the rest of my application.

app.module.ts

```
    LaunchDarklyService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: function(launchDarklyService: LaunchDarklyService) {

        async function asyncLaunchDarklyInitializer(): Promise<void> {
          await launchDarklyService.initializeFlags();
        }
        return (asyncLaunchDarklyInitializer);
      },
      deps: [LaunchDarklyService],
      multi: true
    }
```

This worked fine, using the sample user key.

```
 this.ldClient = initialize("YOUR-CLIENT-SIDE-ID",
      { key: "SAMPLE-USER-KEY", anonymous: true });
```

However to populate the launchdarkly.service.ts with a user key to identify my users I need to inject my user.service.ts.

When I try to do that the application fails to initialize and I get an error 'Invalid user specified.'. I suspect the user service is not loading correctly before my launchdarkly service, leaving me with an undefined user.

How can I get the user Id from my user service, into my launch darkly service before the application initializes?

My user service has the following function

```
 async getUserId(): Promise<string> {
    if (this.isTest)) {
      return this.$storage.read(StorageTypes.LOCAL, 'testId')
    }
    return (await this.$auth.getIdToken())?.userId;
  }
```

I have tried adding my user service as another App_initializer but that didn't work. I then tried to add two promises to my App_Initializer but that didn't work either

```
  LaunchDarklyService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: function(userService: UserService,launchDarklyService: LaunchDarklyService) {
        async function asyncUserIdInitializer(): Promise<void> {
          await userService.getUserId();
        }
        async function asyncLaunchDarklyInitializer(): Promise<void> {
          await launchDarklyService.initializeFlags();
        }
        // return (asyncLaunchDarklyInitializer);
        async function load(): Promise<void>{
          await Promise.all([asyncUserGuidInitializer(), asyncLaunchDarklyInitializer()]);
        }

        return (load);
      },
      deps: [LaunchDarklyService, UserService],
      multi: true
    }
```

And I tried creating a function in my launch darkly service to await a promise from my user service but that didn't work either.

```
  async getUserID(): Promise<void>{
    await this._userService.getUserGuid().then(res => {this.userID = res.toString();})
  }
```

Everything I try results in my application failing to load due to the launchdarkly service not initializing correctly.